# Fill pytable using SQL query

Tags: python, postgresql, cursor, psycopg2, pytables

I would like to use a dataset equivalent in Python. I want to fill a dataset with data using psycopg2's `cursor.fetchall()` and then all future queries from this dataset.

I have learned that pytables can be used in a similar fashion. My question is how to fill a pytable object using the output of `cursor.fetchall()` without a row by row loop? Also how to perform a SQL-like query in pytables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
table.append(cursor.fetchall())
```